# Boolean operators on grep in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm organizing some gatherings, and I've been storing the names and phone extensions in an R dataframe.

```
names <- c("Adrian Xavier", "Berta Xavier",
           "Charles Yamazaki", "Daniela Yamazaki",
           "Edward Zachary", "Fiona Zachary")
phonex <- c(4739, 3894,
            7238, 7459,
            7573, 9457)
people <- data.frame("Name"=names, "PhoneX"=phonex)
```

To invite the Yamazakis only, I prepare the list by

```
only_y <- people[grep("Yamazaki", people$"Name"), ]
```

and to prepare a list that excludes the same set, I run:

```
exclude_y <- people[grep("Yamazaki", people$"Name", invert=TRUE), ]
```

How do I prepare a list that excludes both the Xaviers and the Yamazakis, but that includes everyone else?

Related questions:

- [R grep: is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13187414/704972)
- [R — Logical grep on multiple variables within data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35370739/704972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `or` in your regular expression.

```
people[!grepl("Yamazaki|Xavier", people$Name), ]

            Name PhoneX
5 Edward Zachary   7573
6  Fiona Zachary   9457
```